# How can I use test data to calculate the MSE for a training model in R?

Tags: r, statistics, cross-validation

```
set.seed(1234)
training.samples=RealEstate$Y.house.price.of.unit.area%>%createDataPartition(p=0.75,list=FALSE)
train.data=RealEstate[training.samples,]
test.data=RealEstate[-training.samples,]
```

```
Price.Model1=lm(Y.house.price.of.unit.area~factor(X1.transaction.date)+
                        X2.house.age+
                        X3.distance.to.the.nearest.MRT.station+
                        X4.number.of.convenience.stores+
                        X5.latitude+
                        X6.longitude,
                data=train.data)
```

Would this be correct?

```
mean((test.data$Y.house.price.of.unit.area-predict(Price.Model1))^2)
```

I'm getting this warning so I'm not sure if I'm doing it right:

> Warning in test.data$Y.house.price.of.unit.area - predict(Price.Model1) :
> longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Comment: Use the `newdata`argument of `predict`. Like this: `predict(Price.Model1, newdata = test.data)`.

Answer (score 0):

Mean squared error is defined as:

[image]

To calculate it in R:

1. Fit the model with the training data
2. Use the test data to get predictions with the `predict()` function
3. Use the predicted and actual values of the test data to calculate MSE

Using some fake data...

```
test_ix <- floor(runif(nrow(mtcars) * 0.2, 1, nrow(mtcars)))
train <- mtcars[-test_ix, ]
X_test <- mtcars[test_ix, ] %>%
  select(!mpg)

y_test <- mtcars[test_ix, "mpg"]

fit <- lm(mpg ~ ., data = train)
yhat <- predict(fit, X_test)

mse <- mean((y_test - yhat) ** 2)
```

To obtain the RMSE take the square root of the MSE.